# how less efficient are atoms at generating magnetic fields than the individual particles they are composed of?

Tags: electromagnetism, particle-physics, magnetic-fields, electric-fields

how less efficient atoms at generating magnetic fields than the individual particles they are composed of? How less efficient are molecules? how less efficient is ordinary matter?